# Django: making a clean username with first_name.last_name

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

instead of a fancy `username`, it would be better for my website to have a normalized username in the form **first_name.last_name**.

It is simple to create the new user with this kind of username

```
username = cleaned_data.get('first_name') + "." + cleaned_data.get('name')
```

but what is the best way to clean both fields in order that they contain:

1. no spaces ex: *Théodore de Banville*
2. no accents ex: *Raphaël LeBlond*
3. any other problematic characters

I thought of using `re` and [`unidecode`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
username = re.sub(r"\s+", "", username).lowercase
username = unidecode(username)
```

but is this enought?

EDIT: here is my current solution:

```
            fname = unicode(self.cleaned_data['first_name'])
            fname = unidecode(fname)
            fname = slugify(fname)
            name = unicode(self.cleaned_data['last_name'])
            name = unidecode(name)
            name = slugify(name)
            username = fname + "." + name
```

Comment: Don't forget you'll have to make them unique at some point, when the second John Smith signs up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's mostly what [`slugify()`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L219) does, but the use of `unidecode()` is a huge improvement. The only change I'd make is to apply `unidecode()` first, then remove the spaces.